# GO GCP SDK auth code to connect gcp project

Tags: go, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

Im using the following code which works as expected, I use from the cli `gcloud auth application-default login` and enter my credentials and I was able to run the code successfully from my macbook.

Now I need to run this code in my CI and we need to use different approach , what should be the approach to get the client_secret
and client_id or service account / some ENV variable, what is the way for doing it via GO code?

```
import "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"

project := "my-project"
region := "my-region"

ctx := context.Background()

c, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, compute.CloudPlatformScope)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

computeService, err := compute.New(c)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

req := computeService.Routers.List(project, region)
if err := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.RouterList) error {
    for _, router := range page.Items {
        // process each `router` resource:
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", router)
        // NAT Gateways are found in router.nats
    }
    return nil
}); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: What CI/CD tooling are you using? If you're using the Cloud Build for example you could use the Google Auth pkg which knows to read the local server metadata to auth. You would then provide the required privilege to your Cloud Build service account in the project. In other cases you might want to create a service account, generate a key and store it in your CI/CD tooling however it recommends storing secrets.

Comment: HI we are using Jenkins, can you provide link/example for the auth lib?also example for service account will be helpful

Comment: Are you running Jenkins on a Google Cloud service or another environment? If yes, your current code will work with appropriate roles assigned to the attached service account, otherwise use @jake-nelson answer or look into Workload Identity Federation.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. [See how does accepting an answer work for info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Jenkins you probably want to start with [how to create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account). It guides you on creating a service account and exporting a key to be set as a var in another CI/CD system.

Then refer to the [docs from the client library](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go#readme-authorization) on how to create a new client with source credential.

e.g.

```
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile("path/to/keyfile.json"))
```

If you provided no source, it would attempt to read the credentials locally and act as the service account running the operation (not applicable in your use case).

Answer (score 0):

Many CIs support the export of specific env vars. Or your script / conf can do it too.

But if you want to run in a CI why you need such configuration? Integration tests?

Some services can be used locally for unit/smoke testing. Like pubsub, there is a way to run a fake/local pubsub to perform some tests.

Or perhaps I did not understand your question, in this case can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks, ahh. my question is if I take the code above or any simple GO sdk code which need to read/update code in my GCP project how should I pass to this code the credentials, currently before I run the code I use `gcloud auth application-default login` which doesn't fits our CI